# Custom CSS Selection/Highlight is not right opacity

Tags: css, highlight

I override the default section styles to the code below. But the the black isn't showing up in full opacity but as a darkish grey.

```
::-moz-selection {
color: #fff;
background-color: #000;
}
::selection {
color: #fff;
background-color: #000;
}

<a>Hello World!</a>
```

Comment: I think that might be the expected behaviour. So for example if you make the text color also #000 it shows up (just). i.e. there's a little bit of transparency applied.

Comment: and there is no way to over ride this default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

With some playing around finally got it to full opacity.

```
  ::-moz-selection { 
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.99);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
}
    
::selection { 
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.99);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
  }
```

Comment: or you could use hex with alpha, by using `#fffffffe` and `#000000fe`

Comment: A related and interesting discussion on the problem with overlapping highlighting is at [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867972/avoid-highlight-selection-overlap-with-css - @cornonthecob was a contributor.